# Spell check and locale

Tags: language-support, dictionary, input-language, spell-checking

I have too many languages in my spell checker and I would like to clean up.
When I say spell checker, I mean the spell checker in Firefox, but also other applications like Tomboy.

The thing is, I have a few language packs installed, which is what I want. I use English as my system language, but I want an (Austrian) German number format and spell check. I'd also like to keep my Hebrew spell checker.
What's more annoying is, that a lot of "regional" dicts were installed. So I have now 9 entries (and I got rid of some already).
I don't mind having German and German (Austria), but I'd like to get rid of German (Belgium) and German (Luxemburg).

In System Settings -> Language Support, I have installed English, German and Hebrew. Apparently that installed also the local variations, because after wiping some myspell/aspell/hunspell dicts off my system, it prompts me that the language support is not complete and if I want to install myspell-en-za and myspell-en-au. But no thanks.
As you can see, I did find some of the packages for local language variants, but not for the others!

aptitude search "~ispell" gives:

```
i   aspell                          - GNU Aspell spell-checker                  
i   aspell-en                       - English dictionary for GNU Aspell         
i   hunspell-de-at                  - Austrian (German) dictionary for hunspell 
i   hunspell-de-de                  - German dictionary for hunspell            
i   hunspell-en-us                  - English_american dictionary for hunspell  
i   libaspell15                     - GNU Aspell spell-checker runtime library  
i   libgtkspell-3-0                 - spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView wi
i A libgtkspell0                    - a spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView 
i   libhunspell-1.3-0               - spell checker and morphological analyzer (
i   myspell-en-gb                   - English_british dictionary for myspell    
i   myspell-he                      - Hebrew dictionary for myspell
```

Searching for "dict" only gives me "dictionaries-common", hyphenation is installed for en and de, searches for "thes"(aurus) etc. also don't give me de-BE or similar.

aptitude search "~ilang" gives:

```
i   language-pack-de                - translation updates for language German   
i   language-pack-de-base           - translations for language German          
i   language-pack-en                - translation updates for language English  
i   language-pack-en-base           - translations for language English         
i   language-pack-gnome-de          - GNOME translation updates for language Ger
i   language-pack-gnome-de-base     - GNOME translations for language German    
i   language-pack-gnome-en          - GNOME translation updates for language Eng
i   language-pack-gnome-en-base     - GNOME translations for language English   
i   language-pack-gnome-he          - GNOME translation updates for language Heb
i A language-pack-gnome-he-base     - GNOME translations for language Hebrew    
i   language-pack-he                - translation updates for language Hebrew   
i A language-pack-he-base           - translations for language Hebrew          
i   language-selector-common        - Language selector for Ubuntu              
i   language-selector-gnome         - Language selector for Ubuntu              
i   libslang2                       - S-Lang programming library - runtime versi
i A libslang2:i386                  - S-Lang programming library - runtime versi
```

I don't have any other languages or dictionary (extensions) installed in firefox (or deactivated them) and these languages also appear in Tomboy.

Any ideas how to get rid of 'em?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corresponding question was asked about [Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299398/mozilla-thunderbird-spellcheck-has-too-many-languages).  The solution provided there worked for me:

- go to go to /usr/share/hunspell/
- delete the languages you do not want (e.g.  `rm de_BE.*` to delete Belgian German)

I am not sure why you got the message about incomplete language support - I didn't have that problem.

But in addition, you may still have manually installed dictionaries in Firefox.  Interestingly, just disabling/uninstalling wasn't enough (e.g. via `Tools | Add-Ons`).  To get rid of the languages I didn't like, I went to `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/extensions` and deleted the dictionalry-folders e.g. `rm -r de_BE*`  that did the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot about this. I tried it now and it works. Weird though. IMHO these packages are broken, if they don't do what one would expect.
Also, for some reason, I had 3 entries for Hebrew. There were dictionaries in the hunspell folder, but there is no hunspell package for hebrew. I removed the myspell package and all three were gone. But I don't need it anyway...